# datatables - change row color while a function is acting on that row

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a datatable which has some data in it, including a boolean 'status' column.

I color the rows based on this 'status', and display a user friendly text based on it.

There is also a button in each row that calls a function (which calls an ajax call, which does some work on the server) which may result in a changed status. After this call, the table data is reloaded, and the new status is displayed.

Since the call to the server can take a few seconds, I would like to display an intermediary status color and message, something like 'Waiting' and change the row color to yellow, then, when the data is reloaded, the color&text will go back to matching the status.

Here is what I have so far, shortened to only show the necessary bits:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
table = $('#table').dataTable(
    {
        'columns' : [ {
            title : 'Status',
            data : 'running'
        }, {
            title : 'Name',
            data : 'name'
        }, {
            title : 'Do Something',
            data : 'running'
        } ],
        'fnRowCallback' : function(row, data, dataIndex, dataIndexFull) {
            if(data.running) {
                $(row).css('background-color', '#DEF1D7');
            } else {
                $(row).css('background-color', '#F0DDDD');
            }
        },
        'columnDefs' : [{
            'targets' : 0,
            'searchable' : false,
            'orderable' : true,
            'className' : 'dt-body-center',
            'render' : function(data, type, full, meta) {
                if (data) {
                    return "Running";
                } else {
                    return "Halted";
                }
            }
        }, {
            'targets' : 2,
            'searchable' : false,
            'orderable' : false,
            'className' : 'dt-body-center',
            'render' : function(data, type, full, meta) {
                var button = document.createElement("button");
                button.innerHTML = "Do something";
                button.setAttribute("onclick", "doSomething(\'" + full.name + "\')");
                if (data) {
                    button.disabled = false;
                } else {
                    button.disabled = true;
                }
                return button.outerHTML;
            }
        } ],
    });

    loadData();
});

function loadData() {
$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : '/url/to/my/data',
    contentType : false,
    processData : false,
    data : null,
    success : function(retData) {
        table.fnClearTable();
        // Add updated data 
        table.fnAddData(retData);
        // Redraw table
        table.fnDraw();
    },
        error : function(request, status, error) {
        // Clear table 
        table.fnClearTable();
        // Redraw table
        table.fnDraw();
    }
});
}

doSomething(name){
    //do some stuff that takes some time

    //after that's done
    loadData();
 }
```

How can I change the row's color in the doSomething method called when the button is pressed? Can I set an id on the row somehow in the `fnRowCallback` and use that id in `doSomething`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about handling onclick as below?

```
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {
    $(this).parents('tr').attr('style','background-color: red')
});
```

May be you can bind onclick whenever you are refreshing your data and upon click of button, you can get its parent tr element and change color of it.

Let me know if this works

Comment: I tried this idea, but for some reason I get "table.row is not a function" which doesn't make any sense, but there it is.

Comment: Well I am anyhow not using that line. Edited answer. can you check